# Disable or reducing app compression when using app bundle

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

Users are getting errors with my app that would only be possible if some of the asset files were modified. I'm guessing this is happening because app bundle is performing some sort of lossy compression.

How can I turn that off?

edit: showing how I use uncompress:

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress 'fst', 'txt', 'int', 'mdl', 'raw', 'csl', 'mat', 'conf', 'bin', 'carpa', 'pb', 'pt', 'vec'
}
```

The relevant files are inside [assets/]model/

I've published apps with more than 150MB inside model/ which is why I think it must be compressed. At the moment `du -hs` in `model/` outputs 148MB, app download size is 125 to 139MB.

Comment: Do you use native code in your app?

Comment: Yes. The assets I have are only used by native code, and that's where the errors are happening.

Comment: Please add some more context to the question. Are you using dynamic feature modules? What's the stacktrace? When does the error occur?

Comment: I'm not asking how to fix the errors. I'm asking about app bundle compression and whether one can disable or reduce it. The stacktraces would not tell you anything. No I'm not using dynamic feature modules.

Answer (score 1):

The Android App Bundle does not modify the assets.

You can reproduce how the APKs are generated by running `bundletool build-apks` locally. See [bundletool documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool).

One possible issue is that if you mmap your assets directly from the APK, then they need to remain uncompressed in the APK, in which case you need to indicate which assets need to remain uncompressed in the final APKs, and you can do so with Gradle using:

```
android {
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'png', 'mp3'
    }
}
```

See https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AaptOptions.html

Comment: Helpful, thanks. Already use noCompress though (they definitely are compressed though, total is more than 150MB ).

Comment: If you use noCompress and they still end up compressed then either you're using it incorrectly or there is a bug on the Android Gradle plugin. If you share a snippet of your usage of noCompress and the path of assets you're trying to leave uncompressed, that would be helpful.

Comment: Updated my opening post.

Comment: With this configuration, do you notice that the assets with those extensions are compressed in the final APKs server to users? Or what's the issue exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Android App Bundle - files inside always compressed, but information what should be noncompressed (aaptOptions.noCompress) seems to be stored somewhere inside the bundle.

When google play generates apks from bundle then:
base.apk - assets and res, which corresponds to aaptOptions.noCompress are not compressed.
"install time" assetpak - all assets are not compressed.
The same happens if you build apks from bundle using bundletool.